# C# and Arduino Timing

Tags: c#, arduino, timedelay

Good day,

I am trying to work with C#, Arduino and a LED power supply. First, C# will send some code sequence to my Arduino to activate my motor. I use encoder on the motor to know its position. When my desired position is reached by the motor, C# will send another sequence to my LED power supply. How to make it work? Now when I send my code, C# will send sequence to my LED power supply when my desired position isn't reached yet. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

C# code:

```
arduino.write("A175");
if(arduino.read=="G") {
  powersuppy.write("S100T000F000F000FC#");
} else { }
```

Arduino Code:

```
if(serial.Available()>0) {
  data=Serial.read();
  if (data=='A') {
    int destination=parseInt(Serial.read());
    for(count; count<destination ;count++) {
      motorgo();
      encoder();
    }
    Serial.write("G");
  }
}
```

Comment: show us your code so far

Comment: c# Code:

arduino.write("A175");
if(arduino.read=="G")
{
powersuppy.write("S100T000F000F000FC#");
}
else
{

}

Arduino Code:
if(serial.Available()>0)
{
data=Serial.read();
if (data=='A')
{
int destination=parseInt(Serial.read());
for(count;count<destination;count++)
{
motorgo();
encoder();
}
Serial.write("G");
}
}

Comment: can you paste it into the question and format it into code by highlighting and pressing Ctrl+K

Comment: Sorry, I use chrome and Ctrl+K doesn't make my highlighted text into code

Comment: Oh ok, I understand, sorry, I am so new in this. And my problem is, it's like C# doesn't wait till my Arduino write 'G' to the PC. So C# take the else option, which is do nothing. I hope I made my question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending "G" to the C# after the for-loop ends. You need to check if position is reached THEN send "G".

Comment: What do motorgo() and encoder() do ?! do they have enough delay, to let the motor move, and check its position ?!

Comment: motorgo() is for activate my motor and encoder() is for counting the tick in my motor. The delay of motor activation is determined by the count of the encoder, and with 'for' code, the delay will be enough.